# Optimizing a 2D array pathfinding algorithm

Tags: java, optimization, path-finding

I am trying to find the shortest path through a map represented as a matrix of 0s and 1s, where 0s are passable space and 1s are impassable walls. The the entrance is at the top left (0, 0) and the exit is at the bottom right (width - 1, height - 1).

My function `solution(int[][] map)` finds the length of the shortest path from the entrance to the exit, where you are allowed to remove one wall as part of the path. The path length is the total number of nodes you pass through, counting both the entrance and exit nodes. Conditions on `map` include that the starting and ending positions are always passable (0), the map will always be solvable, though you may or may not need to remove a wall, and that the height and width of the map can be from 2 to 20. Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are allowed.

**A couple test cases:**

Input:

```
int[][] a = {{0, 1, 1, 0}, 
             {0, 0, 0, 1}, 
             {1, 1, 0, 0}, 
             {1, 1, 1, 0}, 
             {1, 1, 1, 0}};
```

Output:

```
8
```

Input:

```
int[][] b = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
             {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
             {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, 
             {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
             {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

Output:

```
9
```

Input:

```
int[][] c = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
             {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
             {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
             {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
             {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

Output:

```
11
```

**My code for my solution is as follows:**

```
public static int solution(int[][] map) {
    int rows = map.length; 
    int cols = map[0].length; 

    Graph graph = new Graph(map);

    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    ArrayList<Node> marked = new ArrayList<>();
    Node start = graph.getNode(0, 0);

    queue.add(start);
    marked.add(start);
    start.setDistanceFromStart(1);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = queue.remove();

        if(current.getX() == rows - 1 && current.getY() == cols - 1) {  //if we have reached goal node
            return current.getDistanceFromStart();
        }

        for(Node n : current.getNeighbors()) {
            queue.add(n);
            n.setDistanceFromStart(current.getDistanceFromStart() + 1);

        }
    }
    return -1; //no path found
}
```

I created two classes with the along with the solution method, Graph and Node:

```
class Graph{
    private Node[][] _nodeMap;

    private int _rows;
    private int _cols;

    public Graph(int[][] map) {
        _nodeMap = new Node[map.length][map[0].length];
        _rows = _nodeMap.length;
        _cols = _nodeMap[0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < _cols; j++) {
                _nodeMap[i][j] = new Node(i, j, map[i][j], false, this);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Node at location (x,y)
     * @param x - the x val of the Node being retrieved
     * @param y - the y val of the Node being retrieved 
     * @return
     */
    public Node getNode(int x, int y) {
        return _nodeMap[x][y];
    }

    /**
     * Replace the node at x,y with the new node n.
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param n
     */
    public void setNode(int x, int y, Node n) {
        _nodeMap[x][y] = n;
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if a node has a neighbor (either a wall or a path) to the north 
     * @param n - the node being checked
     * @return boolean - true if there is a neighbor, false if there is not
     */
    public boolean hasNorth(Node n) {
        if(n.getX() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Return's the neighbor to the north
     * @param n - the current node
     * @return Returns the Node to the north of n
     */
    public Node getNorth(Node n) {
        return _nodeMap[n.getX() - 1][n.getY()];
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if a node has a neighbor (either a wall or a path) to the south 
     * @param n - the node being checked
     * @return boolean - true if there is a neighbor, false if there is not
     */
    public boolean hasSouth(Node n) {
        if(n.getX() < _rows - 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return's the neighbor to the south
     * @param n - the current node
     * @return Returns the Node to the south of n
     */
    public Node getSouth(Node n) {
        return _nodeMap[n.getX() + 1][n.getY()];
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if a node has a neighbor (either a wall or a path) to the east 
     * @param n - the node being checked
     * @return boolean - true if there is a neighbor, false if there is not
     */
    public boolean hasEast(Node n) {
        if(n.getY() < _cols - 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return's the neighbor to the east
     * @param n - the current node
     * @return Returns the Node to the east of n
     */
    public Node getEast(Node n) {
        return _nodeMap[n.getX()][n.getY() + 1];
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if a node has a neighbor (either a wall or a path) to the west 
     * @param n - the node being checked
     * @return boolean - true if there is a neighbor, false if there is not
     */
    public boolean hasWest(Node n) {
        if(n.getY() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return's the neighbor to the west
     * @param n - the current node
     * @return Returns the Node to the west of n
     */
    public Node getWest(Node n) {
        return _nodeMap[n.getX()][n.getY() - 1];
    }
}



class Node {
    private int _x; //x location
    private int _y; //y location
    private int _type; //1 if a wall, 0 if a path
    private Graph _map;
    private int _distFromStart;
    private boolean _wallRemoved;

    public Node(int x, int y, int type, boolean wallRemoved, Graph map){
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _type = type;
        _wallRemoved = wallRemoved;
        _map = map;
        _distFromStart = -1;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return _x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return _y;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return _type;
    }

    public boolean getWallRemoved() {
        return _wallRemoved;
    }

    public int getDistanceFromStart() {
        return _distFromStart;
    }

    public void setDistanceFromStart(int distance) {
        _distFromStart = distance;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an ArrayList<Node> containing the neighbors of a node.
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<Node> getNeighbors(){
        ArrayList<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();

        if(this._wallRemoved) { //if a wall has already been removed
            if(_map.hasWest(this) && _map.getWest(this)._type == 0) { //check west neighbor
                Node node = _map.getWest(this);
                Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), true, _map/*, node._timesEvaluated + 1*/);
                neighbors.add(n);
            }

            if(_map.hasEast(this) && _map.getEast(this)._type == 0) { //check east neighbor
                Node node = _map.getEast(this);
                Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), true, _map);
                neighbors.add(n);
            }

            if(_map.hasNorth(this) && _map.getNorth(this)._type == 0) { //check north neighbor
                Node node = _map.getNorth(this);
                Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), true, _map);
                neighbors.add(n);
            }

            if(_map.hasSouth(this) && _map.getSouth(this)._type == 0) { //check south neighbor
                Node node = _map.getSouth(this);
                Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), true, _map/);
                neighbors.add(n);
            }

        } else { //if a wall hasn't been removed yet

            if(_map.hasWest(this)) { //check west neighbor
                if(_map.getWest(this)._type == 1) { //if west neighbor is a wall
                    if(!this._wallRemoved) {
                        Node node = _map.getWest(this);
                        Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), true, _map);
                        neighbors.add(n);
                    }
                } else { //if west neighbor is a path
                    Node node = _map.getWest(this);
                    Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), false, _map);
                    neighbors.add(n);
                }
            }

            if(_map.hasEast(this)) { //check east neighbor
                if(_map.getEast(this)._type == 1) {
                    if(!this._wallRemoved) {
                        Node node = _map.getEast(this);
                        Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), true, _map);
                        neighbors.add(n);
                    }
                } else {
                    Node node = _map.getEast(this);
                    Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), false, _map);
                    neighbors.add(n);
                }
            }


            if(_map.hasNorth(this)) { //check north neighbor
                if(_map.getNorth(this)._type == 1) {
                    if(!this._wallRemoved) {
                        Node node = _map.getNorth(this);
                        Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), true, _map);
                        neighbors.add(n);
                    }
                } else {
                    Node node = _map.getNorth(this);
                    Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), false, _map);
                    neighbors.add(n);
                }
            }

            if(_map.hasSouth(this)) { //check south neighbor
                if(_map.getSouth(this)._type == 1) {
                    if(!this._wallRemoved) {
                        Node node = _map.getSouth(this);
                        Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), true, _map);
                        neighbors.add(n);
                    }
                } else {
                    Node node = _map.getSouth(this);
                    Node n = new Node(node.getX(), node.getY(), node.getType(), false, _map);
                    neighbors.add(n);
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }
}
```

My code works, the correct answer is returned for each test case.  My issue is that the code is terribly slow.  I'm pretty sure that the maze is being solved by brute force (if not, the time constraint is at least similar to brute force) causing large maps (such as a 20x20 map) to take a very long time to solve.  How can this I optimize my code to make it run more quickly? Thanks!

Comment: Hey! When you have no problem and search for improvements for working code, post the question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this ArrayList called "marked". I would suggest to use it ;)

```
for(Node n : current.getNeighbors()) {
    if(!marked.contains(n)){
        queue.add(n);
        n.setDistanceFromStart(current.getDistanceFromStart() + 1);
        marked.add(n);
    }
}
```

This reduces the complexity to O(n * m), where n,m are the dimensions of the grid.

Also read about BFS algoritm in 2d space. Good luck :)

EDIT #1

If you would like to improve the code more then that try to check [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Also instead of the Queue you can keep all "in progress" nodes on PriorityQueue 
 with special parameter which will try to choose the best node. This parameter can be the distance in cartesian plane between the node and (width - 1, height - 1) (simple Pythagoras' Theorem).
Good Luck again :)

Comment: **"**_PriorityQueue with special parameter_**"** this is what Dijkstra algorithm does with `getDistanceFromStart()` that is already implemented.

Comment: @c0der Dijkstra Algorithm sorts nods in order from  the closest to the farthest from the beginning and works on any typy of graph, even without Cartesian plane. The other solution takes the distance in straight line  from the node to the end which is just an approximation in order  to reduce best-case complexity, and doesn't change the worst-case complexity. Dijkstra have to be implemented with such solution to work properly. The algorithm I wrote about is simple BFS, but with some-kind-of priority check.

Comment: I think you are referring to  Pure Heuristic Search aka greedy best-first search.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this can be helpful 
Union Find from Princeton
https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf

[image]

Comment: This solution, which jest Union Find Algorithm, only determines whether the path exists not giving the shortest one. The complexity of "Disjoint-set data structure", the proper name for it, is O(log*(n)) for Find(node), O(log*(n)) for Union(n1, n2) and O(n) to set up. As far as n is the number of nodes it works as fast as bfs in 2d space checking every node.